# jQuery pagination with scroll back function and some features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I want to a add pagination to my project. I found over 50+ plugins for jQuery to make this. But I don't fine plugin that met all my needs.

I needs:

1) "Scroll Back" - function that if scroll through the list of pages to the end - turn over the back. Endless scrolling.

2) Disabling link to some pages in the dinamics.There is a list of pages and the ability to change the style of a block page so that it was on the list, but it was impossible to open it.

Please, look a picture:
[image]

Is it reallyy find plugin or add this functioons to existing?

Comment: Why can't you modify an existing plugin or write your own?

Comment: Such a specialist plugin would best be custom coded.